# UnitTesting : COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework

I Have created one UnitTesting Project in C# and facing some issues.

Firstly, I wanted to do some Connect functionality that should happen only once in the beginning.
After that i am trying to read some records from Excel file and testing some insert operations and each time insert happens TestCleanUp() gets fired after that constructor gets called then Initialize method.
I dont want constructor to get fire after each record is inserted only once.
I am confused where to put my Connect functionality and how to avoid calling constructor every time.

```
[TestClass]
    public class TestConnection
    {
        private TestContext testContextInstance;
        private static iCAM70003SDKC o_DeviceControl = null;

        /// <summary>
        ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
        ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
        ///</summary>
        public TestContext TestContext
        {
            get
            {
                return testContextInstance;
            }
            set
            {
                testContextInstance = value;
            }
        }



        [ClassInitialize()]   
        public static void Initialize()
        {

            int iResult = 0;
            EOperationalMode OperationalMode;



        }
```

Now i am able to make a initial connection in ClassInitialize as suggested.
Now as i am creating instance of my COM object in ClassInitialize now making initial connection.
Now i have different Testmethod to be tested .
Now when i run my program i get Exception after executing first testmethod "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used”?

I guess when it is trying to execute second testmethod COM object is getting destroyed.
How to keep this COM object alive ? 
I am not calling ReleaseCOMObject.

Comment: If a COM object is created on an STA thread, that thread owns it -- when the thread exits, any .NET RCW objects you still have that point to that COM object are now disconnected from it.  Sounds like your testing framework is calling each method from a different thread. -- So, when the thread for one call shuts down, the object gets disconnected, and then a new thread starts up for the next method and gets this issue.  You can try a `Trace.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` from each method and see if each method returns the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a static method decorated with [ClassInitalize] which will only run once for the test class. This is a great place to establish an initial connection.

Comment: How to access connection details from Excel file as Testcontext is null in ClassInitialize

Comment: Do you have a TestContext parameter on the method, like this? [ClassInitialize()]public static void ClassInit(TestContext context) {} (See the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute(v=vs.100).aspx) for more info)

Comment: How i can read values from Excel in Class Attribute context.DataRow is null while context.TestMethod is coming proper

Answer (score 1):

Yeah use [ClassInitialize] attribute on your initialize method. This would run only once for your class.

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void Initialize() { ... }
```

If you are using NUnit the equivalent would be [TestFixtureSetup]

Make sure your TestContext is public so that it wont be null

Below link can help you if you still face null problem
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsautotest/thread/e9beee26-4927-4a60-b306-555f47cb3958/

Comment: How i can read values from Excel in Class Attribute context.DataRow is null while context.TestMethod is coming proper